# How to know if there is an ongoing api call in Android Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a kind of lazy API call I need to make in my app, that should happen in the background, at specific intervals throughout the day. However, I do not want this call to happen if there is another API call currently being made in the app.

I could use an application-level flag that will be set before a request is made and unset on complete or error, but that solution will not look neat, and the different API calls can be overlapping.

Is there a way in retrofit2 to check if the `Retrofit` object is currently handling an API call? Thanks for any help or pointer in the right direction.

Comment: you can store a `flag` in `shared preferences` and `negate` the flag on response or failure of the request !